# Pytest file not covered (0 percent lines covered)

Tags: python, bash, code-coverage

I am using the python coverage package to determine line percent coverage for the following file

```
coverage report -m math_test.py
```

Once running the command however I ended up having 0 lines covered.

```
import example
import pytest
import unittest

class SampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testAddition(self):
       expected = 10
       math_addition = example.add(5,5)
       self.assertEqual(math_addition, expected)

def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Answer (score 0):

Running math_test.py won't do anything. It defines a class and a function, but doesn't do anything with either of them.  Coverage.py is not a test runner. You need to use something like pytest or unittest to run the tests:

```
coverage run -m unittest discover
coverage report -m
```